# Constructing and deleting object containg vector of pointers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make sure my code is free of memory leaks. I have some items of a custom class and a box-class containg pointers to these items.

```
struct Item{int x;};
struct Box{ vector<Item*>; };

item_1 = new Item{5};
item_1 = new Item{7};
Box* b = new Box{vector<Item*> {item_1, item_2}};

//When it's time to clear memory
delete b;
delete item_1;
delete item_2;
```

I'm curious about the vector of pointers here. Is it stored on the heap too? And does it get deleted in the above example? And what would be the best way to write proper constructors/destructors for 'Box', in this case?

Comment: The vector is inside the box, so wherever the box is, that's also where the vector is. (That is, it works like real-world objects do. Put a box of stuff in the attic, and everything inside the box also ends up in the attic.)

Comment: the member needs a name, and whether `delete item_1` and `delete item_2` are correct depends very much on where those pointers are coming from

Comment: "_I'm trying to make sure my code is free of memory leaks_" - Did you try not using raw pointers at all? The code you've shown does not need them.

Comment: I vote to close as the code is not complete enough to understand the question. Also, just don't use `new` and `delete`, and the problems are all gone. RAII can be your best friend!

Comment: unless you have a good reason you shouldn't use raw pointer, use a smart pointer or even better just use object.

Comment: You are using owning raw pointers, raw pointers that the user is responsible for remembering to `delete`. This should be avoided in modern C++ and raw owning pointers should generally replaced by `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of `T*`. For example `std::unique_ptr<Box> b` and `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>`.

Comment: @François Andrieux The consensus seems to be that unique pointers are the best way. However, in my (much longer) real code I also want to keep a separate list of all 'Item's, in particular I want to draw each of them on the screen in a specific order without having to loop through all the boxes. Is something like this possible with smart pointers?

Comment: @underscore_d I added the definition of the Items, hope this clarifies the question

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo This was a simpliefied example, in my real code I want to do things like keep a separate list of all items and sort this in different ways

Comment: @Jompa It is. The unique pointer is the pointer that is responsible for `delete`ing the object when the pointer is destroyed. But you can also have other, non-owning raw pointers to that object. `std::unique_ptr` has a `get()` member function to get a raw pointer to the owned object. Just be careful not to try to use any raw pointers after the object has been destroyed.

Comment: @Jompa I see - but I do similar things all the time without resorting to raw owning pointers.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks - so I understand that the vector will be stored on the heap too. But what about my delete b;, does it take care of deletion of the vector inside b, or do I need to manually delete this vector in the destructor for Box?

Comment: @Jompa You should never `delete` anything that you didn't create with `new`. (To continue the analogy: if you throw out the box you put in the attic, what happens to the things that are inside it? Do they also end up the trash with the box, or do you need to throw them out separately?)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is absolutely **not** free of memory leaks. Any exception will cause your code to leak memory. That's why in C++ we have [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

In C++:

- **never** use explicit `new`/`delete` in user code
- **never** user owning raw pointers
- try and use objects instead of pointers to objects if that is possible. E.g. you can and should write `Box b = Box{...}`
- when you do need owning pointers **always** use smart pointers (e.g. [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr))

> and what would be the best way to write proper constructors/destructors for 'Box', in this case?

The proper way to write constructors/destructors is to not write copy/move constructors and destructor. However if `Box` is polymorphic then you must make the destructor virtual: `virtual ~Box() = default;`

Comment: That's only if `Box` might be deleted polymorphically, i.e. via a pointer-to-base. Otherwise, the virtual destructor is not needed and could incur unnecessary (probably slight) cost. Still, I guess some people would prefer to have it anyway, if they can't control what users might do with the class and don't want to just say 'GIGO!'. The advise AFAIK is where possible, make the destructor either `protected` and non-virtual or `public` and `virtual`, and in either case `= default` it if possible, i.e. if it has nothing special to do.